# :hover not going back to original state

Tags: css, hover

I am doing a hover over effect for my nav (text and images)
Starting out with a tray look then upon hover they lighten up. 
This effect is working but after the mouse leaves the item it does not go back to its original state apart from in firefox.

Below is a small working object of it without the images and logo. 
http://jsfiddle.net/bjxCn/

They seem to go back to the orginal state after doing a scroll to the left or down normally. Seems very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're nesting *div* elements rather than *li* inside *ul*.  That <s>may or may not be</s> is not valid HTML; when I replaced the ul-div-li layout, the weird hover issue went away (albeit breaking the layout):  http://jsfiddle.net/GppCG/